# Convert array variables names to string

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

How to convert variables names inside array or matrix to string in matlab, so for example if I have :

```
variable1 = 2;
variable2 = 5;
variable3 = 6;

variables_array = {
{[variable1 variable2 variable3]}
{[variable3 variable2 variable1]}
}
```

how to display string like (variable names, not the values)

`[variable3 variable2 variable1]`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I am asking because this just smells like a bad software design decision.

Comment: I'd like to emphasise @Ander's question, because [variable names should not be named dynamically](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval). Using a struct or cell array instead is likely a better way to structure your code.

Comment: thanks for your notes, yes it seems not optimal from software designing point of view, but I have system with dynamic variables order, and I was wondering if there is an easy way to display the parameters name beside parameters values each time I use certain parameters subset

Comment: There should be no reason to avoid using a struct, then you can just output all of the fieldnames and corresponding values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to visualize, what Ander and Wolfie suggest, and how you possibly can use that, here is small code snippet (also, have a look at how to [generate field names from variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)):

```matlab
% Variable names (May be dynamically created by superordinate system?)
varNames = {'x', 'yy', 'zzzZZZ'};

% Values created by superordinate system
values = [1, 4.5, 22.322];

% Mimic variable and value generation of superordinate system
for k = 1:numel(varNames)
  variable = varNames{k};
  value = values(k);

  % Superordinate system should store variables and values in struct.
  sysStruct.(variable) = value;
end

% Content of struct
sysStruct
```

This would give the following output, which I assume is exactly, what you want!?

```matlab
sysStruct =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    x =  1
    yy =  4.5000
    zzzZZZ =  22.322
```